# Flask Jinja Template - format a string to currency

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way to format a string to currency (USD) in a Flask template?

example:
    mystring = "10000"

My desired result would be: `mynewstring = "$10,000.00"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jinja2 provides a way to format values passing to the template. It is known as *custom template filtering*.

To display the currency format in templates from numeric string:

- Create a custom filter in Flask app
- Call the filter in template. Detail on custom filter can be found in
  [official documentation
  here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.template_filter).

You may use string formatting to format the string or Locale as @Blitzer's answer.
As @Blitzer has already provided with `locale` usage, I am adding the string format in the custom filter.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.template_filter()
def currencyFormat(value):
    value = float(value)
    return "${:,.2f}".format(value)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    data = "10000"
    return render_template("currency.html", data=data)

app.run(debug=True)
```

`currency.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Locale Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Locale Example</h3>
        {% if data %}
            <div>{{ data | currencyFormat }}</div>            
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: output of Flask custom filtering]

Comment: Very good answer. I didn't even know template filtering was a thing. (Although I'm sure it's in the docs).

Answer (score 2):

You may use locale for conversion in Flask code

```
@app.template_filter('conv_curr')
def conv_curr(amount): 
  import locale 
  locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8') 
  return locale.currency(amount)
```

Then use a filter

```
{{ 10000|conv_curr }}
```

Comment: Can you use locale inside of a Flask template?

Comment: Edited with filter definition.
Details on how to define and call filters can be read here
https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/explore-flask/chapter-8/custom-filters